# How to create form for collection or how to read check box value in index.haml (or .erb)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, collections

In my project I get data to temporary table and after checking would like to click some check boxes in listing in `index.haml` and only marked records move to main table.

I found a [similar solution in here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes?autoplay=true), but it was 8 years ago and I could not create working example.

Another author wrote 3 years ago:

> "Forms are for entities, not for collections."

I can accept even just to update the table by marking records corresponding to selected check boxes - further is obvious. How can I create a working example for Rails 4?

Thanks for respond. Finally I found the solution. If someone is still  interesting:

I created a project as simple as posiible. Here two tables: tasks and temptasks. Task contains only “name”, temptask contains “name” and “for_moving” which will be updated through check boxes.

Controller:

```
class TasktempsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_tasktemp, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @tasktemps = Tasktemp.all
end

def new
     @tasktemp = Tasktemp.new
end

def edit
end
```

...

```
 def create

     if params[:tasktemp_ids].nil? || params[:tasktemp_ids].empty? 
         @tasktemp = Tasktemp.new(tasktemp_params)
         respond_to do |format|
             if @tasktemp.save
                  format.html { redirect_to @tasktemp, notice: 'Tasktemp was successfully created.' }
                  format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tasktemp }
             else
                 format.html { render :new }
                 format.json { render json: @tasktemp.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
              end
         end
    else
        @tasktemps = Tasktemp.where('id ==?', params[:tasktemp_ids])
        @tasktemps.update_all(["for_moving=1"])
    end
 end
```

…

view:

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing Tasktemps</h1>
<%= form_tag @temptasks do %>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>For_moving</th>
                 <th></th>
                 <th></th>
                 <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <% @tasktemps.each do |tasktemp| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= tasktemp.name %></td>
                    <td><%= check_box_tag "tasktemp_ids[]", tasktemp.id %>
                    <td><%= link_to 'Show', tasktemp %></td>
                    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_tasktemp_path(tasktemp) %></td>
                    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', tasktemp, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
                </tr>
        <% end %>
     </tbody>
</table>

<br />
<%= submit_tag "Mark as Complete" %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'New Tasktemp', new_tasktemp_path %>
```

create.html.erb:

```
<%= "Records are updated"  %>
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :tasktemps
    resources :tasks
    root to: 'tasktemps#index'
end
```

This example works. The heart of the solution was to put in 'create' action two different actions: for new record and for for updated through check boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Link

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box

this will for sure help you.